# How to remove few strings from a whole line in ansible?

Tags: ansible

rem    par   str        how to remove few strings

I need to remove rem, par, str from the whole line

Comment: Provide the input and desired output. And what did you try so far?

Comment: See the example below. Is this what you want? [edit] the question and make it [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will be closed otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The main point of this rebus is to remove the strings only and leave the words starting and potentially ending by these strings untouched. The solution is starting and ending the *regexp* by matching an empty string at word boundary `\b`. This will keep the words starting and ending by these strings untouched. Add `\s?` to match one space after the string if exists. This will match the strings at the end of the line as well.

Use the module [*replace*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html#ansible-builtin-replace-module-replace-all-instances-of-a-particular-string-in-a-file-using-a-back-referenced-regular-expression). For example, given the file

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/test.txt 
rem par str how to remove few strings
```

Put the strings you want to remove into a list

```yaml
  remove_strings: [rem, par, str]
```

Iterate the list

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: /tmp/test.txt
        regexp: '\b{{ item }}\b\s?'
        replace: ''
      loop: "{{ remove_strings }}"
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.txt 
how to remove few strings
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    remove_strings: [rem, par, str]
  tasks:
    - replace:
        path: /tmp/test.txt
        regexp: '\b{{ item }}\b\s?'
        replace: ''
      loop: "{{ remove_strings }}"
```